# Data modeling in Cassandra

Tags: data-modeling, cassandra

I'm building a data base where some users can put tag in others data. Something like Last.fm. How can I implement a DB in cassandra for this application. The Tag must be associate with the user and the data.

Is there any data modeling pattern for cassandra?

The Stack overflow tags is a good example of what I want to do! :)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://maxgrinev.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/ and the other articles at the top of http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArticlesAndPresentations

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already built this in a conventional database I would suggest that first.  Most people don't have the data scale to need something like Cassandra.  Otherwise if this is simply a project and you want to try out Cassandra then I suggest this link to get you started:

[Cassandra by Example : Twitter](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/cassandra-by-example/)